# Stop Returning SNS plot when a function is called

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Here is the Python code. I am using a function here which should return a float value. However, it is also returning the graph as sns.distplot is called. Is there any way to only return the numeric value?

```
  data = []
  for idx, var in enumerate(df):
    myPlot = sns.distplot(df['Acceleration'])
    lines2D = [obj for obj in myPlot.findobj() if str(type(obj)) == "<class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'>"]
    x, y = lines2D[idx].get_data()[0], lines2D[idx].get_data()[1]
    data.append(pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y}))
  
  limit=pd.DataFrame(data[0]).loc[data[0]['y']>=0.01]['x']
  limit=limit.values.tolist()
  off= df[(df.Acceleration< limit[0]) | (df.Acceleration>limit[-1])]
  
  return len(off)/len(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using jupyter:
I don't think your graph is returned by the function, it is simply displayed while "working" your function. Try inserting `plt.close()` at the end of your for loop block and I'm sure your plot won't show anymore. I've tried it and it works, the sns plot display will be suppressed. Make sure to put `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the top of your file.